# is it possible to write image to csv file?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, docx

Hi everyone this is my first post here and wanted to know how can ı write image files that ı scraped from a website to a csv file or if its not possible to write on csv how can ı write this header,description,time info and image to a maybe word file Here is the code
Everything works perfectly just wanna know how can ı write the images that i downloaded to disk to a csv or word file
Thanks for your helps

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site_link = requests.get("websitenamehere").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(site_link,"lxml")

read_file = open("blogger.csv","w",encoding="UTF-8")
csv_writer = csv.writer(read_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["Header","links","Publish Time"])
counter = 0

for article in soup.find_all("article"):
    ###Counting lines
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

    #Article Headers
    headers = article.find("a")["title"]
    print(headers)

    #### Links
    links = article.find("a")["href"]
    print(links)

    #### Publish time
    publish_time = article.find("div",class_="mkdf-post-info-date entry-date published updated")
    publish_time = publish_time.a.text.strip()
    print(publish_time)

    ###image links
    images = article.find("img",class_="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image nitro-lazy")["nitro-lazy-src"]
    print(images)

    ###Download Article Pictures to disk
    pic_name = f"{counter}.jpg"
    with open(pic_name, 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.get(images, stream=True)
        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            handle.write(block)

    ###CSV Rows
    csv_writer.writerow([headers, links, publish_time])
    print()

read_file.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried? If I search for 'write image to csv' on SO then I get lots of results. Also, does it have to be converted to csv/word? Why not as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could basically convert to base64 and write to a file as you need it

```
import base64

with open("image.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string= base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
    print(encoded_string.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: thanks i understand the concept of what your and other comments mean

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is supposed to only contain text fields. Even if the csv module does its best to quote fields to allow almost any character in them, including the separator or a new line, it is not able to process NULL characters that could exist in an image file.

That means that you will have to encode the image bytes if you want to store them in a csv file. Base64 is a well known format natively supported by the Python Standard Library. So you could change you code to:

```
import base64
...

    ###Download Article Pictures
    response = requests.get(images, stream=True)
    image = b''.join(block for block in response.iter_content(1024))  # raw image bytes
    image = base64.b64encode(image)                    # base 64 encoded (text) string

    ###CSV Rows
    csv_writer.writerow([headers, links, publish_time, image])
```

Simply the image will have to be decoded before being used...